# Would it be possible to emulate a ps4 controller on USB-out

Tags: usb, usb-hub

Would it be possible to create a PlayStation 4 controller USB interceptor of sorts for the purpose of using macros? The project’s model would look like this:

• You are plugging PS4 controller in one of the RPi’s USB ports

• Button pushes are recorded by RPi

• Macros are sent to USB out

• RPi’s USB out goes to PS4 USB port

What would stop this from being doable? I am not familiar with USB protocol, what would be some good resources to read? Is it possible to emulate a device on RPi via USB port?

Comment: 1) You have to do this as a kernel module. 2) Kernel modules can only be written in C. 1 + 2 + "I am not familiar with USB protocol" imply this is likely to be very far from a trivial task for you, unless you can find something existing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: focus on one thing at a time ... start with emulating a controller

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for a reply. I was mainly wondering about setbacks and needed to be pointed in the right direction. I’ll start learning USB and how it is implemented in the PS4 controller. It can’t be that hard… Can it?…

Comment: Here's a resource for how to implement a PS4 controller. https://github.com/passinglink/passinglink Of note is that the PS4 has an authentication scheme that requires the controller to provide a secret key in order to function. Acquiring such a secret key legally means applying to Sony for a controller licence.